# Pass multiple variables between the two contained frames

Tags: c#, javascript, iframe, frame

Someone help me out.
I have 2 Iframes and one container.aspx page

1) container.aspx page has links for other two frames in it.

2) Both frames src pages have a associated code behind file with it i.e. something.aspx.**cs** page

how do I pass multiple variables between the two contained frames using the code behind file.
I know how to do this in javascript but my requirement is in c#...asp.net.

Can someone guide me. and help appreciatd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way of doing this is use the ASP.NET session object
 http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/

Unless you have a database you can write to. Then you can share the values through the database

Comment: No I dont have a database to share the values..but i can surely try using the session variables..is it possible to trigger a reload/refresh the page or receiving iFrame when a the session variable is changed.

Comment: you cant trigger an execute on the other page without notifying it, (i guess auto refreshing every x second is not what you want). so when page 1 changes a session value, you have to notify the other page to refresh with javascript.

Comment: is it possible for you to show me a sample trigger/notification function for this..